# Mule 3.6 : Log4j2: How to read java vm arguments

Tags: mule, log4j2

Is there a way to read java vm arguments in log4j2.xml ?
${jvmrunargs:argname} does not work.
My arguments in Mule's wrapper.conf have to be read in log 4j log pattern.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

${sys} works. The documentation is not so descriptive.. but does cover this

Answer (score -1):

According to [log4j2 documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#PropertySubstitution) jvmrunargs can be

> A JVM input argument accessed through JMX, but not a main argument

Is that your case?

Comment: No. I have simple jvm arguments provided when starting the java process

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried the [Main Arguments lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html%23AppMainArgsLookup)?

In your code, you need to manually provide the main arguments of the application to Log4j:

```
import org.apache.logging.log4j.core.lookup.MapLookup;
public static void main(String args[]) {
  MapLookup.setMainArguments(args);
  ...
}
```

Then in configuration you can do:

```
<File name="Application" fileName="application.log">
  <PatternLayout header="Startup params: ${main:0} ${main:1} ${main:2}">
    <Pattern>%d %m%n</Pattern>
  </PatternLayout>
</File>
```

Comment: I do not have that option. I am using Mule ESB and am providing arguments from mule configuration

Comment: Then I'm afraid log4j2 cannot help you.